# R - Is for(x in x) valid?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am writing a function in R and have an input `id` that is a numeric vector.

Can I write a for loop that states:

```
for(id in id)
{
    /****/
}
```

and loop over the `id` vector with the variable `id` or will this cause problem?

Comment: The real question is why would you want to write such confusing code that you have to ask if it's legal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will produce the expected result but it will destroy the `id` to the right  of the `in`.  Also within the loop all references to `id` will be the `id` to the left of `in` so you won't be able to reference the one on the right.

```
> id <-  1:3
> for(id in id) print(id)
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
> id
[1] 3
```

Try writing it like this to be safer:

```
ids <- 1:3
for(id in ids) print(id)
```